# # Imported Obj-C class through automatically created Bridging header, Bridging header seems to find it but Swift class won't

Tags: objective-c, swift, import, header, bridging-header

1. I added the files directly to my project from finder to Xcode.
2. Bridging header was automatically created by Xcode.
3. **#import** the Class into the Bridging header - no issues on the Bridging Header.
4. I try to instantiate Class var into swift class - "*use of undeclared type*" error shows up.

   - Notes: When I try to **COMMAND + click** on the **#import** I get the message "Symbol Not Found".

Comment: Please post your code and a link to a screenshot of your User-Defined build settings in Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that file (**A.swift**) that was trying to reference the "other file" (**B.swift**) had "**test target membership**" selected! So **I either had to** add the "other file"(**B.swift**) to the test target membership **or remove** file (**A.swift**) from the test target membership. I hope that makes sense and that it is of help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your bridging filename set to the "Objective-C Bridging Header" field under the Swift Compiler section in Build Settings for it to be included by the Compiler.
[image]

"Symbol Not Found" is just an Xcode bug, I get that but I have no issues using bridged files.

Comment: So I did all of that again. I still get "**Use of undeclared type**".